# Compilation error in C++ reading files

Tags: c++, file, c++11, error-handling, compiler-errors

I've compiled a .cpp file with g++ and the only errors I had were like this:

```
histogram.cpp:24:26: error: ignoring return value of ‘size_t fread(void*, size_t, size_t, FILE*)’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Werror=unused-result]
 fread(&altura,4,1,fp);
                      ^
```

I know I'm using a very restrictive flags which treat warnings as errors, but trying to fix this errors I failed, so if someone can bring some light in this problem I'll be very pleased.
The flags I'm using are:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Werror -O3  histogram.cpp -o histogram
```

Thank you.

Comment: `fread` returns a `size_t` value but you're not doing anything with the return (in essence treating it like a `void` function). Try assigning the result of `fread` to a variable of type `size_t`.

Comment: That return value is there for a reason. If the `fread` doesn't do what you're asking, don't you want to know that is the case?

Comment: For once, the error message is not to blame. Just as it clearly says: You are ignoring a return value you are not supposed to ignore.

Comment: @EliSadoff  I'm using this return value to fill a matrix, like this:        fread(&intr,1,1,fp);
         matrizRed[i][j]=intr

Comment: `trying to fix this errors I failed` how exactly did you try to fix this error? Did you not try doing to opposite of what the warning is complaining about? In other words, didn't you try to *not ignore* the return value.

Comment: Suppose, say, that the program that wrote the file was terminated unexpectedly.  Maybe it failed, maybe the user aborted it, maybe there was a power-outage.  What do you expect *altura* to contain?  Why would you consider continuing to run your program with bad data?  What are the odds that this in turn will make your program fail or generate a nonsense result that happens to look "normal"?   This will not happen when you test your program, you'll get a difficult to answer phone call.

Comment: @giorgioW You're not using the return value to fill a matrix. You're using `intr`. This function does not return `intr`.

Comment: @BaummitAugen but I'm ignoring this return value because I don't need it. `fread` function are returning directly the values I need to the variables that I've declared for this. `fread(&MyVariable,4,1,fp);`

Comment: @giorgioW You do need it, namely to determine whether or not the read operation succeeded. As it stands now, you have no way to tell whether `altura` contains any sensible data after `fread` returns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you don't use the return value of "fread", you need something like this:

```
  size_t result = fread (buffer, 1, lSize, pFile);
  if (result > 0) 
  // do smthng
```

instead of

```
fread (buffer,1,lSize,pFile);
```

Comment: The return value can be cast to `void`, as in `(void) fread(buffer, 1, lSize, pFile);`